# UIImageanimation with UIView Animation Blocks

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, uiimageview

I want to use UIView Animation with blocks instead of UIImageview Animation. As I need to know when the animation finished I decided to use UIView Animation with blocks which I am new to.
So I want this:

```
NSMutableArray *mixedimages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

for(int count = 1; count <= 5; count++)
    {
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Picture_%d.jpg", count];
        UIImage  *frame    = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
        [mixedimages addObject:frame];
    }


gamePicture.animationImages = mixedimages;

gamePicture.animationDuration = 1;
gamePicture.animationRepeatCount = 10;

[gamePicture startAnimating];
```

Into this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{

    //animation code here
} completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    NSLog(@"Animation finished");
}];
```

But I don't know what code to fill in that will do the same as above, so that I will have the same kind of animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use UIView animation to animate UIImageView's content. UIView animation can only animate a fixed set of UIView properties:

```
@property frame
@property bounds
@property center
@property transform
@property alpha
@property backgroundColor
@property contentStretch
```

To work around the lack of a completion block for UIImageView, you can refer to the answers here:

[iPhone : Best way to detect the end of UIImageView image sequence animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770997/iphone-best-way-to-detect-the-end-of-uiimageview-image-sequence-animation)

Comment: Is there any other way to animate images?